# Redis value fetch for 3000 keyhash takes about 10 seconds(python 3.5)

Tags: python, performance, redis

I am new to REDIS world. I am trying to fetch values for 3000 keys from REDIS. Each hash has 6 values that I want to fetch. I am using Python 3.5 to to make connection to REDIS one time and then loop through my key hashs to get their respective values from REDIS. However, currently it is taking about 10 seconds to get the values for these 3000 rows. I am using the below code to get data from REDIS. Can you please help me in speeding up the fetch. Is there a way to send all the keys at once and get the values related to them? I am using python 3.5 for this.

```
redis_pool = redis.ConnectionPool(host='XYZ',
                                  port='XY',
                                  db='X')
r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=red_pool)

field1 = r.hmget(primary_key, "Field1")
```

Comment: is this just one hash and 3000 fields or 3000 hash?

Comment: and In your code it is just `hget`

Comment: @GuangshengZuo it is 3000 hash with 6 values per Key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try [pipeline](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining) to speed up your query.

```
r = redis.Redis(connection_pool=red_pool)
pipe = r.pipeline()
for key in keys_list: 
    pipe.hget(key, "field1")
results = pipe.execute()
```

The `results` will be the list of every hget reply. you could refer [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py)'s readme's pipeline section to learn more about how to use pipeline in python redis client.

Comment: Thank you @GuangshengZuo for your reply. I will get back to you tomorrow about the time(performance) it takes using this approach.

Comment: I used pipeline and it helped in getting down the time from nearly 10 seconds to 5-6 seconds. Is there any other way to speedup this query from REDIS end?

Comment: I am afraid that if you do not change the data type you use in redis and if you always have to iterate all the hash keys, there is no way to speedup in redis end. But if you just want to get all values in once, then you should not use hash, you could jut put all the values in a list , and use `lrange` to get them.

Comment: I will look into that. Thank you for your help. For now I am using r.hgetall and this also helped in improving the performance. But pipeline did the major performance improvement.